# How to keep Angular Route nav fixed ? Angular Route redirecting to new page

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am following the tutorial. I need to keep The nav bar fixed and neviagte like [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovkvayplpbm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.

I have only two links. This is inside of one page.

Here what I have tried.

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/title" routerLinkActive="active">Titler</a>
    <a routerLink="/dist" routerLinkActive="active">Dist</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and

```
HttpClientModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(Inner, {
    enableTracing: true
  }),
RouterModule.forChild([ HOME_ROUTE ]),
```

and the Route.ts is

```
import { Route, Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: [],
        pageTitle: 'home.title'
    }
};

export const Inner: Routes = [
    {path: 'title', component: TComponent},
    {path: 'dist', component: DComponent}
];
```

If I click to the Like it Redirect to new page . But like that Example I want to keep the nav in everypage and show the Content. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: could you create a complete example on stackblitz ( since your seems familiar with it ? ) There are some unclear things in your question ( like using RouterModule.forRoot and forChild in the same module ?? )

Comment: acutally I am not familiar with stackblitz .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, [here is a stackblitz of the simplest routing example I can imagine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplest-routing-example).
If the example doesn't answer your question, feel free to update it and use it in your question. (don't be scared of stackblitz, it's just an online IDE ^_^))

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly or correct me

Please create a component ex. header.component and add you nav tag in header component
and then you can write

```
<header-component></header-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

you can add it to app.component.ts
and it will be available in all pages